# Statsmodels-AIC- How to calculate Delta AIC

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels, lme4

I use statsmodels lme module.

I have 2 models with the same y-variable and different fixed variables.

Both models are random intercept models.

I want to compare them. I found out that I can use AIC but in R I saw computations such as Delta AIC giving additional info about comparison and I could not find them in Python. How can I calculate that? And Is it possible to use WAIC in lme models? As I saw, it only supports AIC. But I wanted to make sure if there is no work-around.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

I found how to compute AICc in python but not the delta one.

For the interested ones to compute AICc:

```
from statsmodels.tools import eval_measures
eval_measures.aicc(llf= xxx, nobs = xxx, df_modelwc= x)
```